# if my retainCount is 4 is that bad for iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Updates code

```
- (void) searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar {
    mytimer3=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.03 target:self selector:@selector(show) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];


        NSLog(@" search is down");  



    //////////// rnd to hold keyboard





     //ovController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];


     self.tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;




     UserText=[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar text];
     myInt= UserText.length;
     //int myInt= [save length];



    // NSString *myStringPrt1 = [[NSString alloc] init];
    // NSString *myStringPrt2 = [[NSString alloc] init];


     if(UserText.length>3)

     {
     //[ovController.view removeFromSuperview];
     //[tableView reloadData];
     url=nil;
    // myStringPrt1=@"http://find.php?keyword=";
    NSString * myStringPrt2=UserText;
    // myStringPrt1=[myStringPrt1 stringByAppendingString:myStringPrt2];
    // myStringPrt1 = [myStringPrt1 stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    // loadingView.hidden=NO;




         NSString *outputString = [[NSString stringWithString:@"http://find.php?keyword="] stringByAppendingString: UserText];
         outputString = [outputString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


         NSLog(@"My string is  now =  %@", outputString);


     url=   [NSURL URLWithString:outputString];



     NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url] autorelease];

     //Initialize the delegate.
     XMLParser *parser = [[[XMLParser alloc] initXMLParser]autorelease];

     //Set delegate
     [xmlParser setDelegate:parser];

     //Start parsing the XML file.
     BOOL success = [xmlParser parse];
     if(success)
     {



         [super viewDidLoad];




     [self searchTableView];    
         mytimer4=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(wipe) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
     }


     }
```

}

Comment: You need to elaborate on your question, and maybe show some of the code you're working with. As it stands, no-one knows what you code is doing or how you've written it, so having a retain count of 4 doesn't tell us anything.

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question? I don't understand what you are doing.

Comment: It should be mentioned that retain counts can be extremely misleading and should almost never be used to find memory errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right, you have memory leaks all over the place:

```
NSString *myStringPrt1 = [[NSString alloc] init];
NSString *myStringPrt2 = [[NSString alloc] init];

url=nil;

myStringPrt1=@"http://wap?keyword="; //MEMORY LEAK, this will assign a new string to myStringPrt1, without releasing the first one
myStringPrt2=UserText; //MEMORY LEAK, this will assign a new string to myStringPrt2, without releasing the first one

myStringPrt1=[myStringPrt1 stringByAppendingString:myStringPrt2]; //MEMORY LEAK, this will assing an autoreleased string the myStringPrt1, without releasing the old one first.
myStringPrt1 = [myStringPrt1 stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; //MEMORY LEAK, this will assing an autoreleased string the myStringPrt1, without releasing the old one first.
```

I suggest you first read the memory management guidelines as indicated by Kubi. Or, if you are feeling lazy, use this:

```
NSString *outputString = [[NSString stringWithString:@"http://wap?keyword="] stringByAppendingString: UserText];
outputString = [outputString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Or this:

```
NSString *outputString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://wap?keyword=%@",UserText];
outputString = [outputString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: To summarize @Rengers' point, it's almost never the right choice to use manually-retained NSString objects. NSString's convenience constructors, which return autoreleased objects, are almost always simpler to use AND free you from memory concerns.

Comment: Actually, the two leaks are `myStringPrt1=@"http://wap?keyword=";` and `myStringPrt2=UserText;`

Comment: @tc: All of the five assignments after `url=nil` cause leaks.

Comment: @Dan Ray: +1 `foo = [[NSString alloc] init]` is almost always wrong since it assigns an empty immutable string to foo the same as `foo = @""`.

Comment: @JeremyP: You're right, I forgot to indicate `myStringPrt2=UserText` one. Good rule of thumb on the `[NSString alloc] init]` as well!

Comment: awsome  thanks for all that information i am glad that i am member of this forum ;-)  one thing i want to ask 
1)if i dont alloc and directly do like this NSString *myStringPrt1 @"http://wap?keyword=";   then i dont have release isnt it ..it will be done by autorelase and
2) whenever you initalize  string in.h then you must have to assing property and then syntezie then only you can use isnt it 
not like in .h you define string *h;  and in .m directly using like this h=@"ddf";  ???

Comment: hey i did what you said 
NSString *outputString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://wap?keyword=%@",UserText];
outputString = [outputString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
but still retaincount=4  is that ok??

Comment: As Kubi pointed out, you should worry about retain count. If you make sure you balance your retain/release count you should be okay.

If you use only those last two lines of code, it should be okay. You could post your 'entire' code in the question if you want to be sure.

Comment: Looks like there are no big apparent leaks, though there is a lot of unnecessary code in there.

Answer (score 4):

**Don't pay any attention to your retain count.** That number will fluctuate for reasons entirely out of your control and trying to determine why the number is what it is will drive you crazy (and not do you any good).

Follow proper [Obj-C memory management guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html), use the [leaks detector in Instruments](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/ViewingandAnalyzingData/ViewingandAnalyzingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH5-SW22), and run the [static analyzer](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/02/clang-static-analyzer.html) when you build. If you do all that, you'll be fine.

Comment: thanks how to use leak detectetor??? i mean whane you will know your code is efficient???
i have seen that graph with some thin pink likes but i dont know what are they  plz explain

Comment: @ram:  kubi even provided a link to the documentation.  Do yourself a favour and *read* it.

Answer (score 0):

No depending on your requirement and object allocation, your retain count will definitely increase. But the main thing you need to keep in mind that release all the allocated object at proper place and proper time.

Comment: NSString *myStringPrt1 = [[NSString alloc] init];
NSString *myStringPrt2 = [[NSString alloc] init];
  
  //if(UserText.length>3
  {
  //[ovController.view removeFromSuperview];
  //[tableView reloadData];
  url=nil;
 myStringPrt1=@"http://wap?keyword=";
  myStringPrt2=UserText;
  myStringPrt1=[myStringPrt1 stringByAppendingString:myStringPrt2];
  myStringPrt1 = [myStringPrt1 stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

then after pasring xml when i trace them
their value is 4
NSLog(@"retain cccd %d",[myStringPrt1 retainCount]);/ its 4

Comment: when user press search button then i am calling the above lines 

when should i release myStringPrt1 and myStringPrt2
or should i use them without alloc??

Comment: one more thing 
malloc: *** error for object 0x4696730: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Wat2Eat(6945,0xa01a7500) malloc: *** error for object 0x4696770: double free
###########################################


can this leads to memory leakage????

Comment: Please, paste this code in your question in a formatted way. This is just unreadable.